# Sticky menu, absolutely positioned, transparent, inside parent container

Tags: css, position, sidebar, sticky, absolute

I have this situation: a parent container with multiple sub-containers in it. It needs a sidebar menu for the content. The menu should be sticky, transparent (above the content) and always positioned in the top left corner of the parent container.
So far, I managed to realize this:

```
<div>
other content
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
   <div class="div-sticky-class">
     sticky menu
     <li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li>
   </div>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</div>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</div> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</div> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</div>
   <div>Lorem ...</div>
  <div>Lorem ...</div>  
</div>

<div>
other content  
</div>
```

style:

```
.parent-div {
  display:block;
  background: #00ccbc;
}
.div-sticky-class{
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 245, 0.75);
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

And is not ok because the content is placed below the menu, not behind it.

It should actually look like this, instead:
[image]

But if I change the position of the menu to absolute, it won't remain sticky then.

Actually I need a sticky sidebar with arbitrary position inside its parent container, not inline or block, that overlaps the rest of the content.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you ment, but try it and let me know.

```
lorem content
<div class="parent-div">
   <div class="div-sticky-class">
     <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
       sticky menu
       <ul>
         <li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   parent content
</div>
lorem content
```

```
.parent-div {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background: #00ccbc;
}
.div-sticky-class{
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 245, 0.75);
}
.sidebar-wrapper{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-bottom: -100px` to the `div-sticky-class` (negative margin of sticky element height)

Comment: Thanks @Dave111; this works in this limited example, but in the real application the sidebar has to have the same height as the parent container, that has its height variable, given by the dynamic content (it's a SPA).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the sidebar will have 100% height of the parent element or the height will depand on the sidebar content?

Comment: It must 100% of the parent. The parent's height is variable, not pre-determined